# Arrays of strings with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

In the following code:

```
int main()
{
   char names[2][11] = {"Manchester","Party"};
   char (*jk)[11];
   jk = names;                    // LINE 1
   char gaming[10] = {"Jetking"};
   char (*po)[10];
   po = &gaming;                  // LINE 2
   cout<<"PO is "<<*po;
```

Line 2 requires me to put & in front of gaming, while Line 1 doesnt. The error it gives for Line 2 when I dont put & is, "error: cannot convert 'char [10]' to 'char (*)[10]' in assignment" ? I didnt quite understand this part. Since "char (*po)[10];" can be interpreted as a pointer to an array of 10 characters.

Comment: `Since "char (*po)[10];" can be interpreted as a pointer to an array of 13 characters.` Not really

Comment: See these two links [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations) and [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Why downvotes? Lol! If I understood it wrong, you could explain..

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, but if you ask or answer [tag:c++] questions, you should get used to it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : What I said was right only. You can refer any article, even the one posted by Olaf. char (*po)[10] refers to an array to 13 characters.

Comment: You get downvotes because this is a nonsense question about how to debug your code for you.

Comment: @UnderDog: No, that is nonsense. `po` is a pointer to an array of 10 characters

Comment: debug? Ha! I could get the required answer in 10 different ways. Only reason I asked is to understand the logic behind what am I doing wrong.

Comment: That is what i meant. po is a pointer to an array of 10 characters. Read what i wrote in the question.. a pointer to an array of 10 characters. You are too hasty and jump onto conclusions too quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assignment

```
jk = names;
```

the array `names` of type `char[2][11]` is converted to a pointer to its first element, thus it decays into a `char (*)[11]`.

`gaming`, however is converted into a `char*` in most contexts, and that `char*` is incompatible with the type that `po` has, `char (*)[10]`, so that assignment is invalid. If you take the address of `gaming`, you get exactly the required `char (*)[10]`.

Comment: exactly thats what I wanted to know. Can you please clarify it further that how am I getting char(*)[10] when I am taking the address.

Comment: That's what the address operator is defined to do, if you take the address of an object of type `T`, it returns a `T*`. I'm not sure what you need explained in that, can you clarify that?

Comment: Just realized. Sorry about that second clarification. This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 1):

`char gaming[10]` is an array of char. When you write `po = gaming`, gaming is converted to a pointer to char for this assignment. `po`, however, is a pointer to an *array* of chars.

So, in the end, the compiler tells you it cannot convert a `pointer to char` to a `pointer to an array of chars`. That's all.

Comment: re "`gaming` is a pointer to char", no, it's an array.

Comment: also, the compiler doesn't "tells you it cannot convert a pointer to char to a pointer to an array of chars".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you for pointing that out. I took the liberty to explain it, just IMHO of course, more understandable. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
char (*po)[10];
```

is a pointer to an array of 10 `char` items.

An array expression doesn't decay to a pointer to itself-as-array. It decays (when it does) to a pointer to first item. Hence, the need for applying address operator, and also the error message you got about being unable to convert the array expression to a pointer-to-array.